# how to implement workers with python script?

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to implement a worker external bash script in my python script , but when I try to run it . I got the error of `/bin/sh: 1: worker.sh: not found` , but my bash script it is in the same folder as my python script .

```
├── tool.py
├── unix.sh
└── worker.sh
```

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
subprocess.call('worker.sh', shell=True)
```

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "worker running"
```

Comment: Are you *executing* your script from the same folder where your bash and python scripts are?

Comment: yeah , but I got the issue of not found

Comment: Is ``worker.sh`` executable?

Comment: it is executable , and it has a permission of 755 , `-rwxr-xr-x`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be:

```
subprocess.call('./worker.sh', shell=True)
```

Using `subprocess.call` is similar to typing the command into a bash window.  So you either need to define the path to `worker.sh` (or add it to your path).